# How to add multiple forms to one Django view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I'm making a web app where in one page,  a user can enter input to a form for the name of an artist, a city, state, and a mile radius and a JSON response is returned from an api call and is parsed on the server side. I then pass this parse data as context variables back to the client to be displayed as elements in a list for each concert event that was returned. In each list element (or for each concert), there is a button that can be clicked to allow the user the send an invite for the concert to a person through smtp. This button click is an event that should do two things.

1. It has to get data embedded within the button and send that to the server-side through an ajax call.
2. Open a modal on the page where the user can specify information that they want to put in the email. This data will then be added to the ajax call to the server-side.

While it seems that I have the general structure for this, the problem is that there doesn't seem to be a way to map multiple forms to one Django view. The form that I currently have for initially getting the user's input for the api call is just made by making an instance of the form object in the view corresponding to the template for the page. As this is the case, I'm not really sure if its possible to have the modal be apart of the same page.

What would be the best way of facilitating the clicking of the button to enter data to send in the email as well as then returning to the original page?
I'm open to any suggestions for restructuring the code.

Here is the code I have to create the list as well as what I have for the ajax call (in the template):

```
var venues = {{venues|safe}};
var dates = {{raw_dts|safe}};
var ticket_statuses = {{ticket_statuses|safe}};
var ticket_urls = {{ticket_urls|safe}};
console.log("length of artist list" + venues.length);
var $list = $("<ul  class='list-group'>");
for(var i = 0; i < venues.length; i++){

    $list.append("<li class='list-group-item'>Artist: {{form_artistSelect}}  Location: " + venues[i].city + ', ' + venues[i].region +' Venue: ' + venues[i].name + 
       "Date: " + dates[i] + "tickets status: " + ticket_statuses[i] + "<br><a href = '" + ticket_urls[i] +"'" + "> ticket link</a> " + 
       {{% if user.is_authenticated %}}
            "<button id ='invite'type='button' class='btn btn-info btn-lg' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' venue= " +venues[i] +" date = "+ dates[i]+ +"ticket_url = "+ticket_urls[i]+" artist = {{form_artistSelect}} >Invite a friend</button>  <button id = 'save' type='button' class='btn btn-primary-outline'> Save concert</button> " + 
        {{% endif %}}
            "</li>"); 
}

$("#invite").click(function() {
    var raw_dt;
    var rec_email; //has to be gotten from the modal
    var message; //has to be gotten from the modal
    var rec_name; //has to be gotten from the modal
    var ticket_url;
    var venue;

    raw_dt = $(this).attr("date");
    venue = $(this).attr("venue");
    ticket_url = $(this).attr("ticket_url");
    $.ajax({
        url: your_url,
        method: 'POST',
        data: {

        }
        success:function(data){
        }
    });
});
```

#### EDIT:

html code for the first form:

```
<body id = "top">

<form id = "search" method= 'POST' action = ''>{% csrf_token %}
{{ form|crispy }} 

<input type= 'submit' value= 'Submit'>
</form><br>
```

html code for the modal:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Invitation</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <div id="container">  </div>
            <form id = "search" method= 'POST' action = ''>{%csrf_token %}
            {{ form|crispy }} 
            <input type= 'submit' value= 'Submit'>
            </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I might misunderstand your intention, but you can add as many forms as you like in django view, as long as they are all rendered within the same `<form>` element in the template.

Comment: I don't understand either; I don't see where in this you need multiple forms on a single view.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Sorry, I forgot to add the code for both forms. I've updated the post now.

Comment: @ShangWang If I have different objects in forms.py for each form, how would I map each form in the template to the corresponding form object?

Comment: Well, you definitely need to give each form object a name before you pass them to the template isn't it? like you have one `form_a = FormA()` and `form_b = FormB()`, then in the context you give each object a name: `c = Context({'form_a': form_a, 'form_b': form_b})`. Read this part of the doc if you are not sure what I'm talking about: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context

Comment: In the template you can just do `{{ form_a | crispy }}` and `{{ form_b | crispy }}`.

Comment: @ShangWang Thanks, the problem I'm having now is that I'm unable to extract the data from the second form as the page is saying ```'ModalForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'``` (ModalForm is the form object for the form inside of the modal).